# Update my php array in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to update or add new key=>value to my php array in javascript function.

The paging is in ajax, page is not reloaded again.

Actually I am receiving the data in a text file which is uploaded on my server. I parse that file and get a limited number of records, when I click on  NEXT then one more file is uploaded on server and I parse it once again and show the data. So, I want that all data to be stored in php array on that page so when next time I go to PREVIOUS record, it doesn't parse the file once again, just show the data from the array.

```
//php array name is $call_data

var file_data = <?php $content = @file_get_contents("text file name"); 
$content = rawurldecode($content); 
$new_call_data = json_decode( $content ); 

foreach ($new_call_data->CALLS as $key => $val) { 
    $call_data['CALLS'][] = $val; $file_rec_start++;
} 
echo json_encode( $call_data ); ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't see the part, where you split your "content" part into peaces so you have to reload the page, is it missing or is this part in JavaScript?

also you could minify you source:

```
<?php
$my_contents = file_get_contents('myfile.json');
$my_contents = rawurldecode($my_contents);
$my_array    = json_decode($content);
$my_json     = json_encode(array_values($my_array->CALLS));
?>
var file_data = <?=$my_json?>;
```

than you can itterate trough the array in javascript without the need of refreshing the page.
you could use

```
var results_per_page  = 25
var page_available = Math.ceil(file_data.length / results_per_page);
var page = 0;
var page_array = file_data.slice((page * results_per_page), ((page+1)*results_per_page));
```